# How do I check in Python if a function belongs to a module

Tags: python, function, module

I have a module that is loaded and I go through all of it's functions to check if they have a certain parameter. If they do, I run those functions;

The problem is the module will also have it's own imports, which add to the function list and some of the functions of the imported module will be run as well. I need to check if one function, given it's address belongs to a certain module.

```
import bar;
def function(special_param):
    #dostuff
```

In `bar` I have a function named `other_function` with `special_param` as well. By importing it, Python imports all of it's functions. How do I check if `other_function` belongs to `bar`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if a function is available in a Python module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763971/determine-if-a-function-is-available-in-a-python-module)

Answer (score 0):

```
if hasattr(bar, 'other_function'):
    do_something()
```

Note that `other_function` might also be a variable in `bar`, not a function.

EDIT: This is a duplicate of: [Determine if a function is available in a Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763971/determine-if-a-function-is-available-in-a-python-module) where a better answer by @macrog is given. Use it instead. (flagged your question as duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
if hasattr(bar, 'other_function'):
        getattr(bar, 'other_function')('Special_parameter')
```