# How to develop an app within Google Apps in php

Tags: google-app-engine

How to develop an app within Google Apps that changes collects incoming mail and adds the content to a new row in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

Your app can receive email at addresses `string@appid.appspotmail.com` if you [use an email address for your app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/#PHP_Receiving_mail) at appengine.

[Receiving Mail in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233201/receiving-mail-in-google-app-engine)

[Set up mail to receive emails on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149322/set-up-mail-to-receive-emails-on-google-app-engine)

Then use google email API and populate spreadsheets in google drive using the documents API with your gae language for instance letting your spreadsheet read RSS, XML, JSON, or text. From the docs:

> Email messages are sent to your app as HTTP POST requests using the
>   following URL:
>
> /_ah/mail/address where address is a full email address, including
>   domain name.
>
> To receive email, you first edit your app's configuration file to
>   include a section that enables incoming mail:
>
> inbound_services:
>   - mail Incoming email in App Engine works by posting HTTP requests containing MIME data to your app. In your configuration file, you must
>   create mappings from URL paths that represent email addresses to
>   handlers in your app's code. The pattern /_ah/mail/.+ matches all
>   incoming email addresses:
>
> - url: /_ah/mail/.+   script: handle_incoming_email.php   login: admin In the app itself, you must implement code in the handlers you
>     specified. The email's MIME data is supplied to your app as the
>     contents of an HTTP POST request, and you process this data in your
>     handlers.