# Testing for specific method in a Python class

Tags: python, oop, class, methods

What is the best (or 'Pythonic') way to test if a class has a specific method defined?

Both of these work but don't feel 'correct' in that in the second one, I just try to access it and trap for an exception if it doesn't exist.

Is there a better / more correct way?

```
class TestClass(object):
    def TestFunc(self):
        pass



if 'TestFunc' in dir(TestClass):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'No'



try:
    if TestClass.__getattribute__(TestClass, 'TestFunc'):
        print 'yes'

except:
    print 'No'
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar():
        pass

assert hasattr(Foo, 'bar')
```

If you really mean to test whether the attribute is a *method*, you could do this:

```
assert hasattr(Foo, 'bar') and callable(getattr(Foo, 'bar'))
```

Comment: Note that this internally works like the second. A big advantage is that the two work even with properties and other things not in the `__dict__`, `__slots__`, etc.

Comment: This won't say if it's a **method** or not - only that it's defined on that class

Comment: @Gerrat, I thought of that, but because the OP's examples did what hasattr does, I assumed that's what he wanted to do. Still, I've edited it to cover the method case.

Answer (score 3):

You're close.

It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than to Ask Permission.

```
try:
    testClassInstance.testFunc()

except AttributeError:
    pass # Ask forgiveness.
```

Don't "pre-test" for things like this.  Assume they exist and cope with their absence.