# Write business rules in elegant way chaining possible nonexistent attributes

Tags: python, business-rules

Take a look to this code:

```
>>> class c(object):
...    pass
... 
>>> a=c()
>>> if a.b.c:
...    print 'hello'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'c' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Quiet! this is not the question. Please, continue reading:

When someone develops enterprise software (with django for example) must write business rules.
This rules looks like

```
if invoice.customer.adress.country in ...:
    invoice.makeSomeSpecialOffer()
```

But some times, one of the objects involveds on expression don't exists. Then, to **avoid errors** I sould rewrite sentence as:

```
if invoice.customer and
   invoice.customer.adress and
   invoice.customer.adress.country and
   invoice.customer.adress.country in ...
```

This is less readable! (also you can try with hasattr but is alse less readable).

My work arround is enclose if statement into a try, but there is a more elegant or pythatonic way to avoid this kind of errors? Which is your favorite technique?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python

Comment: @ditkin, thanks about this link!. But my question is not to know if a object has an attribute, is how to write code in an elegant way  chaining possible missing attributes. I have changed title. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What kinds of objects are `invoice`, `custom`, `address` etc.?

Answer (score 2):

To check chained attributes the following function might help:

```
def get_chainedattr(parobj, *args):
    try:        
        ret = parobj
        for arg in args:
            ret = getattr(ret, arg)   
        return ret
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

I am not sure if it is more readable but by using this function your example can be written as:

```
if get_chainedattr(invoice, "customer", "adress", "country") in ...:
   invoice.makeSomeSpecialOffer()
```

Comment: This is out-rightly wrong. Please read the section [except](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#except) in the article Idioms and Anti-Idioms in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add the exception name. Do you see a problem in the answer now?

Comment: I liked your approach but somehow the way you caught the exception was not right. After you corrected it, this is indeed good.

Answer (score 1):

> This is less readable! (also you can try with hasattr but is alse less
>   readable).

Another option would be to enclose in a `try` '`except` block.

```
try:
    if invoice.customer.adress.country in ...:
        invoice.makeSomeSpecialOffer()
except AttributeError:
    None
```

Either you can make a proactive check like `hasattr` or a reactive like try-except. Readability is a perception and both the approach is except-able.

Comment: Yes, this is my work around as I explain in question: "My work arround is enclose if statement into a try"

Comment: @danihp I just read the above post, but unfortunately this is something you shouldn't do. Please read the link in my comment.

Comment: Sorry. I don't speack english correctly, That I want to say is: I know this is a solution as I explain in my question, I ask for other ways to do this. You talk about 'another option' but this is not another option, this option is enclosed in question text because this I can't mark your question as right. I check @boracaglayan answer as solution that is more close to question statement. Thanks about your time. Also, where is the link of your comment?

Comment: Comment next to the above post. In brief you should not catch an exceptions unconditionally.

Comment: Sorry, I have not a way to check both questions as solution. Is not easy for me. I uncheck bora answer as solution to keep both answere as the same level. Also, where you write None, is not [pass](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) more pythatonic?