# How to check if the object has property in view in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the documents property in a general function, but a few models may not have the documents attribute. Is there any way to first check if a model has the documents property, and then conditionally run code?

```
if self.model has property documents:
    context['documents'] = self.get_object().documents.()
```

Comment: Why are you ever using a model that doesn't have it there?

Comment: I have generic view which displays all the models in single template. Initially i didn't have any documents but now few of them has documents attached. so i was thinking if there is some way to check othwise , i need to define the new view with 90% same code. For hackish solution i have made a function with try and except so that i don't get any error in site but was looking for proper way

Comment: Why don't you have the model tell which view it should use, with a sane default?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `hasattr()` to check to see if model has the documents property.

```
if hasattr(self.model, 'documents'):
    doStuff(self.model.documents)
```

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610923/1269296) points out that some people feel the "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" approach is better practice.

```
try:
    doStuff(self.model.documents)
except AttributeError:
    otherStuff()
```