# What's the difference between hasattr() and 'attribute' in dir()?

Tags: python

For example:

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> hasattr(s, 'join')
True
>>> 'join' in dir(s)
True
```

[Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) says that `hasattr` is implemented calling `getattr` and seeing whether it raises an exception or not. However, that leads to a great overhead, since the value obtained is discarded and an exception may be raised.

The question is if calling `'attribute' in dir(obj)` means the same thing, is it faster, safe, or may it fail in a particular occasion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not quite the same thing. `dir()` is a diagnostic tool that *omits* attributes that `getattr()` and `hasattr()` would find.

From the [`dir()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> The default `dir()` mechanism behaves differently with different types of objects, as it attempts to produce the **most relevant, rather than complete**, information:
>
> - If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the module’s attributes.
> - If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.
> - Otherwise, the list contains the object’s attributes’ names, the names of its class’s attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its class’s base classes.

and

> **Note**: Because `dir()` is supplied **primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt**, it tries to supply an interesting
>   set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently
>   defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across
>   releases. For example, `metaclass` attributes are not in the result
>   list when the argument is a class.

Emphasis mine.

This means that `hasattr()` will find *metaclass supplied* attributes, but `dir()` would not, and what is found can differ accross Python releases as the definition for the function is to provide debugging convenience, not completeness.

Demo of the specific metaclass scenario, where `hasattr()` finds the metaclass-defined attribute:

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...     foo = 'bar'
... 
>>> class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
...     pass
... 
>>> hasattr(Foo, 'foo')
True
>>> 'foo' in dir(Foo)
False
```

Last but not least:

> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called and must return the list of attributes.

This means that `hasattr()` and `dir()` can vary even more widely in what attributes are 'found' if a `.__dir__()` method has been implemented.

Just stick with `hasattr()`. It is faster, for one, because testing for an attribute is cheap as that's just a membership test against one or more dictionaries. Enumerating all dictionary keys and merging them across instance, class and base classes on the other hand has a far higher CPU cost.

Comment: A drawback of using `hasattr` is that it will trigger properties execution, which may be costy. In cases such as a Django `OneToOneField` relations, this will even trigger a database query. I don't suppose there is an alternative, is there?

Comment: @AugustoMen: You can use *application specific* means of testing for an attribute being present. I'm sure Django has a means of enumerating fields, for example.

Answer (score 7):

the hasattr is more than 100 times faster :)

```
In [137]: s ='string'

In [138]: %timeit hasattr(s, 'join')
10000000 loops, best of 3: 157 ns per loop

In [139]: %timeit 'join' in dir(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.3 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

`dir()` does not call `getattr()`, or anything like that,  It depends on the class to "describe" itself:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __dir__(self):
...         return ['apples', 'bananas', 'mangoes']
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         return {'a': 1}[attr]
...     
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> hasattr(foo, 'a')
True
>>> hasattr(foo, 'apples')
False
>>> 'a' in dir(foo)
False
>>> 'apples' in dir(foo)
True
```

You should only use `dir()` when looking for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

hasattr() is basically

```
try:
    s.attribute
    return True
except AttributeError:
    return False
```

while "attribute in dir(s)" is more like:

```
for attr in dir(s):
    if attribute == attr:
        return True
return False
```

Hence, hasattr is expected to be a bit faster.

Anyways, if I be allowed to go a bit off-track then I would suggest this.
If you want to do something like:

```
if hasattr(s, 'attributeName'):
    s.attributeName()
else:
    do_stuff()
```

then its advisable to do it like this:

```
try:
    s.attributeName()
except AttributeError:
    do_stuff()
```

Why?

1. To avoid the overhead of an extra try-except block/ for loop.
2. In python, it's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission.

Comment: Downvoted because the advice at the bottom is wrong: with the second piece of code you don’t know if the `AttributeError` was raised because `s` has no `attributeName` or because the code executed by `s.attributeName()` raised that exception.