# How to verify Class attribute or method exists

Tags: python

I apology ahead if this is a repost. 
I'm currently using a following "self-invented" verification method to check if a Class's attribute (or method) exists before trying to access it:

```
if 'methodName' in dir(myClassInstance): result=myClassInstance.methodName()
```

I wonder if there is a more common "standardized" way of doing the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if an object has an attribute in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#hasattr). It returns `True` if a given object has a given name as an attribute, else `False`:

```
if hasattr(myClassInstance, 'methodName'):
    ...  # Whatever you want to do as a result.
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Do you think there are any side-effects if I would keep using if 'methodName' in dir(myClassInstance)? How much more "reliable" hasattr() is?

Comment: @Sputnix Although, you will have to wait fifteen minutes before it allows you, unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `hasattr(myClassInstance, 'methodName')`.

Another possibility is to just try accessing it and handle the exception if it's not there:

```
try:
   myClassInstance.methodName()
except AttributeError:
   # do what you need to do if the method isn't there
```

How you'll want to handle this depends on why you're doing the check, how common it is for the object to not have that attribute, and what you want to do if it's not there.