# How to guarantee Python function is passed only a single variable, not list or array?

Tags: python

I have a Python function that I would like to guarantee has been fed a variable, list, tuple, or Numpy array or matrix that consists **only** of a single number: `2`,`(2)`,`[2]`, etc.  If the function has been passed a tuple, list, array, etc. that consists of more than one value I would like it to raise an error or exception.  The function would look something like this:

```
def f(x):
   #check if x is a single variable
   if(x.shape != (1)):
      #Error or exception and quit
   else:
      #keep working
```

However, when I run (for example) `f(2)` I am told that `'int' object has no attribute 'shape'`.  I am trying to figure out the correct way to do what I describe above in general sense, so that whether `x` is a variable, tuple, list, whatever the function can recognize whether it has a single variable or not.

Comment: See: [How to know if an object has an attribute in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python). i.e. `hasattr(x, 'shape')`

Comment: For a one-element array of numpy the `.shape` is `(1,)`, not `(1)`

Comment: can't you make sure that the input it receives is narrowed down at least somewhat at the source? Otherwise you'll just need to add a bunch of if/else statements checking its `type` and `len` respectively. (e.g. a normal list doesn't have a shape either)

Comment: in your particular example, shape is a method from x. This is because you are assuming that x is a numpy object. Insted of that, you have to use general methods. If you change, for instance x.shape as np.shape(x), it will work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Calling this "a single variable" is pretty misleading. An array value or list value can be stored in a single variable, exactly the same way an integer can.

Comment: you can use `len` and `isinstance`

Comment: @abarnert, if `x` is a single element list or array I want it to go through the function just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `shape`, you either need to wrap it in `try`/`except`, or type-check first. (The former is usually better.)

Also, note that `(1)` is not a 1-element tuple, it's just the number 1. Tuples are made by commas, not by parentheses.

But there's a bigger problem here: `shape` doesn't exist on lists, tuples, or other collections, only on NumPy arrays. So, you'll need a second fallback to deal with them. You could use the built-in `len` function, which works on all sized containers, or you could use `np.shape`, which works on all containers that NumPy knows how to convert to arrays (while everything else will end up as a single-element scalar of dtype `object`, so its `shape` will be `()`). I'm not sure which is appropriate in this case. (One question to help decide the answer: does a 10-element dict count as having length 10, or 0?)

Maybe something like this:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        if x.shape != (1,):
            # Error or exception
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            if len(x) != 1:
                # Error or exception
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

However, note that strings have a size—a string is an iterable over its individual characters—and yet, often, you want to treat them as singular values.

More generally, an API that can take either a single value or a collection of values is usually a sign of something wrong with the design elsewhere in the program. Why aren't you generating single-value collections in the first place? Sometimes there's no way around this, because you're accepting values from someone else's code, or directly from the end-user—but make sure that's really true before going out of your way to overcomplicate things.

Comment: The code you wrote, as far as I can tell, does what I want it.   I am not familiar with dictionaries, so I cannot answer that question.  The reason why I am not generating single-value collections in the first place is because I am accepting input from an end-user.

Comment: @Joshua: But what format are you accepting it in? Unless you're calling `eval` on Python code entered by a user or something, there has to be some interface that you can define. Anyway, if you don't know enough to care about about `len(x)` or `np.shape(x)`, I guess just pick one at random and use it until you have a problem?