# PuppetDb Python script get fact if exists?

Tags: python, puppet

I'm using the [PuppetDb python library](https://github.com/voxpupuli/pypuppetdb). I want to print the value of a fact if it exists.

```
for group in groups:
  node = puppetdb.node(group[0])
  if hasattr(node.facts, 'custom_fact'):
    print node.fact('custom_fact')
```

I'm relatively new to python but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610893/773263) that the above method should allow me to check if an object has an attribute.

Not sure if I misunderstood the instructions or if a PuppetDb object acts differently.

How can I print `custom_fact` only if it exists?

---

*Edit: when I use `print node.facts` it says that `node.facts` is a bound method.
So I'm trying this also (with `osfamily` fact because it should always return something):*

```
for group in groups:
  node = puppetdb.node(group[0])
  facts = node.facts()
  print facts
  if hasattr(facts, 'osfamily'):
    print facts('osfamily')
```

*`print facts` returns `<generator object facts at 0x7f906ffe35f0>`*

*`print node.facts('custom_fact')` is never run.*

*Also trying `dir(facts)` to look for attributes which doesn't return anything, which leads me to believe this isn't a normal object.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found using `try/except` works better:

```
for group in groups:
  print group[0]
  node = puppetdb.node(group[0])
  try:
    print node.fact('custom_fact').value
  except:
    pass
```