# Testing for None throws an error the attribute doesn't exist

Tags: python

```
----> 1 if person.network is None:
      2     print('person.network does not exist')
      3 

AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'network'
```

As you can see on line 1, I'm checking if 'network' doesn't exist. However, when it doesn't exist it fails and throws a python error. I'm a bit lost as to how this is happening. Shouldn't line 1 catch this exact problem?

The actual code properly goes through about 10 records before failing when one of them doesn't have 'network' defined.

Comment: An attribute that doesn't exist is different from an attribute set to None.

Comment: you are probably looking to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python).

Comment: Use `hasattr()`

Comment: Sounds like a data dependent issue tied to your specific code. You'll need to provide more context to debug why the buggy instance is raising the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between an instance attribute having the value of `None` and it not existing at all (your case). To properly check whether an instance attribute exist, you can use the `hasattr()` method:

```
if hasattr(person, "network"):
    # do stuff
```

If you need to retrieve the value, you can do so safely using `getattr()`:

```
network = getattr(person, "network", None)
```

The last parameter is the default value to be returned in case person does not have the `network` attribute.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in python function hasattr :

```
    if hasattr(person, "network") :
```