# How to handle object null in python

Tags: python-3.x, null

I am using flask. When I do not pass StartingSequenceNumber to flask app then How can I handle null object.

```
  class Meta():


    def __init__(self, j):
        self.__dict__ = json.loads(j)
```

in bootstrap.py

```
   meta = Meta(request.get_data().decode())
   if meta.StartingSequenceNumber is not None:
     # do something
```

Error : AttributeError: 'Meta' object has no attribute 'StartingSequenceNumber'

Comment: did you try exception handling?

Comment: I can. But is there no way without exception handling?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `hasattr()` built-in function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) which will return True if the object has the attribute :

```
if hasattr(object, 'attribute'): 
    # do smthg
else:
    # do smthg else
```

But it would be better to used `try & except` blocks and throw an `AttributeError`

```
try:
    doSmthg()
except AttributeError:
    # do smthg else
```