# PynamoDB - How to use scan(attributes_to_get=[...])

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using `pynamodb==3.3.3` to scan items with the `attributes_to_get` condition, but get an exception that I can't solve:

```
  File "/Users/user/Documents/project/script.py", line 250, in filter_writable_snapshots
    existing_snapshots = ItemSnapshot.scan(attributes_to_get=['id'])
  File "/Users/user/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pynamodb/models.py", line 790, in scan
    filters=filters
  File "/Users/users/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pynamodb/models.py", line 1050, in _build_filters
    raise ValueError("Attribute {0} specified for filter does not exist.".format(attr_name))
ValueError: Attribute attributes_to_get specified for filter does not exist.
```

The model has a field `id`.

```
from pynamodb.models import Model
from pynamodb.attributes import UnicodeAttribute

class ItemSnapshot(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'my_table'

    id = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    other_field = UnicodeAttribute()
```

I am trying to load only the `id` field.

```
existing_snapshots = ItemSnapshot.scan(attributes_to_get=['id'])
```

Am I doing anything wrong here or why is the request crashing? The strack trace looks like it would try to find the attribute `attributes_to_get` which doesn't make any sense to me.

I already check that the class's attribute `id` [does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610893/1309035).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `.scan()` don't have parameter `attributes_to_get`. This available on `.query()` and `.rate_limited_scan()` methods.

Comment: The method `.scan()` now has the parameter `attributes_to_get` that would project the provided field names as a list of str. https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pynamodb.models.Model.scan