# How to retrieve attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attr

```
class character():

  class personalized:
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, width, hair_color, eye_color):

      # I want to do this
      for attr in personalized:
        personalized.attr = attr


      #instead of this
      personalized.name = name
      personalized.age = age
      personalized.height = height
```

If I am using classes with a lot of attributes I don't want to have to set it equal to a variable every time because it will take up a lot of space. Is there a way to write it like I did above but actually works. In essence I don't know how to retrieve attributes from the `__init__` function.

Comment: Attributes don't exist until you add them. There's no way for the `__init__` method to know what attributes you want to use in the class.

Comment: You can't access parameter variables dynamically, unless you use `eval()`.

Comment: also consider refractoring the class so it doesn't have to own all of those argument, therefore having to set less variables in your class.

Comment: Pass a kwargs-style dict to `init()`, instead of individual arguments.  That way you can loop over the dict and extract the variable names.

Comment: @Barmar `setattr(self,'parameter',value)` will create an instance variable dynamically.

Comment: But just do it the long way. The code is clear. Or use `dataclass` if using Python 3.7+ if this is a data structure and not a class with other methods.

Comment: @MarkTolonen But how would it know which attributes to create?

Comment: @Barmar I didn’t say it was a solution, just a comment about your `eval`  comment.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I was talking about accessing the parameter variables dynamically, not the attributes. E.g. `setattr(self, parameter, eval(parameter))`

Comment: @Barmar Still don't need `eval`.  `vars()` can access the parameter names and values.  I made an answer with that solution, although think dataclasses are a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for this. In your case you would just add:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class personalized:
    name: str
    age: int
    height: int
    width: int
    hair_color: str
    eye_color: str
```

This will auto-construct a **init** for you with self-assigned attributes

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `__set__(..)` Function (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), but I do not suggest this because:

- From a readability perspective this will harder to maintain over the long term (code is more often read than written)
- everytime you want to access such an entry you first of all have to check if the descriptor/attribute is availible, thus making your down the road code worse.
  see:
  [How to know if an object has an attribute in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) and [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) can do what you want, but I recommend [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) as in the other answer if using Python 3.7+.

`vars()` returns a dictionary of local variables.  At the top of `__init__` dictionary contains `self` and any parameters as keys and along with their values.

`setattr()` will set an attribute value on an object.

```
class Personalized:
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, width, hair_color, eye_color):
      for key,value in vars().items():
          if key != 'self':
              setattr(self, key, value)

p = Personalized('name',5,10,12,'black','blue')
print(p.name,p.age,p.height,p.width,p.hair_color,p.eye_color)
```

Output:

```
name 5 10 12 black blue
```